# How to set validation for dynamically add row/remov row in formvalidation io

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on form validations in add/remove row.but my form validations not working. Please give me solution for this.
I added all js and css libraries.
Mycode

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 1000; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".document_upload_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_document_button"); //Add button ID
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            appendclone = '<div class="form-group removedocumentdiv"><div class="col-sm-2">'+
            '<label for="">Document</label></div><div class="col-sm-3">'+
            '<input type="file" class="form-control" id="documentsupload[]" name="documentsupload[]"/>'+ 
            '</div><div class="col-sm-1"><a class="remove_document_field" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Remove">'+
            '<i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>'+
            '</div></div>';//add input box
            $(wrapper).append(appendclone); 
            $('#visaapplicationform').formValidation('addField', $(this).find('[name="documentsupload[]"]'));
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_document_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).closest('div .removedocumentdiv').remove();
        x--;
    })

});
```

Html code

```
<div class="document_upload_wrap">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                          <label for=""> Document</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                          <input type="file" class="form-control" id="documentsupload[]" name="documentsupload[]"/>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-sm-1">
                                             <a class="add_document_button"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
```

Please give me solution for this

Comment: What is the error? Also, is there any error message in the browser's console?

Comment: console also no errors. but form submitted without showing validation